# Which is the default fontsize of the text in the row of a datagrid?

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

How I could know how is the defaults values of the standard WPF datagrid in .net 4.7.2?

I special, I would like to know how is the default value of the fontsize.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default font size of the standard WPF datagrid in .net 4.7.2 is 12
The default font size is determined by the FontSize dependency property of the TextElement class